# Is there any way to get latest news using Google api in Java

Tags: java, feed

I want to create simple web application , which will have all latest news from sports or cinema.

But i am confuse about the approach,Can anybody tell me is there any way to get latest news using google api in java or is there any other way to get latest news using Java.

Comment: I knows about RSS feed , but i want to know which are the all available ways to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Network News Transfer Protocol(NNTP)`.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides an RSS feed (for non-commercial use) [here](http://support.google.com/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59255). And then you can create your simple application (if you want to explicitly create a web application) using the code [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.feedzilla.com) to get the latest news in your web application.